# Tkinter crashing when trying to load long text string into new window

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I have a problem where tkinter is crashing when I try to load a text string of length 96000.

```
window2 = Tk()
window2.title("Days")

welcome = Label(window2, text="Please click date", background="black", foreground="white")
welcome.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

def June_28():
   june_window = Toplevel(window2)
   june_window.title("June 28 Updates")
   the_june = Label(june_window, text=atext, foreground="black")
   the_june.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=3,sticky='w')

def July_27():
   july_window = Toplevel(window2)
   july_window.title("July 27  Updates")
   the_july = Label(july_window, text="Here is july 27", foreground="black")
   the_july.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3)

junes = Button(window2, text="06/28/202", command=June_28)
junes.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1)

julys = Button(window2, text="07/22/202", command=July_27)
julys.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=1)
window2.mainloop()
```

Atext is the string with greater than 96000 elements.

Comment: Why would you create a label with 96,000 characters? You can't scroll labels so you won't be able to see all of the data.

Comment: What should i do instead to display this?

Comment: The text widget would be best, since it can wrap text of give you a scrollbar for scrolling the text. I'm not sure if either of those will handle 96,000 characters though.

Comment: Typo error, in line 13, should be `text=anext`, instead of `atext`.